# Is 'do' needed in this sentence? and is comma needed?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, commas

Seeing the amount of these sheets accompanying each medication, I have realised how much paper (do) we waste on a daily basis?

Seeing the amount of these sheets accompanying each medication I have realised how much paper (do) we waste on a daily basis?

Comment: It's certainly not "needed" - it's actually ***ungrammatical*** (or at least, ***seriously non-idiomatic***) to include ***do*** that way in the cited utterance. In certain "emphatic refutation / surprise" contexts, it would be possible to say *I've realised how much paper we **do** waste* (where some prior context implied there's little or no such waste). But your example isn't one of those contexts. The comma would normally be included (as would a pause in speech), but I wouldn't say it's *required*.

Comment: "I have realised how much paper (do) we waste on a daily basis?" is written like a question, but is not one.

Answer (score 2):

A direct question inverts the subject and auxiliary, requiring "do-support" for most verbs:

> How much paper *do we* waste on a daily basis?

An indirect or embedded question does not invert, and so does not require "do-support":

> I've realised how much paper *we* waste on a daily basis.

We always have the option of emphatic *do*, but there is no inversion in the embedded question:

> I've realised how much paper we **do** waste on a daily basis!

Answer (score 0):

Better to say the number (or quantity) of sheets. Leave out 'do'.
You can leave out 'these'. I would only use it if indicating the sheets to someone present at the time.